# I've wrote code on an outdated version of QisKit but what to run it on a quantum computer

Tags: qiskit, ibm-q-experience, ibm-quantum-devices

like mentioned in the title I've got working code on an outdated version of QisKit which I run on my own IDE. However I am wanting to run this on a real quantum computer and I can't do this as IBM quantum lab only works for the current version of QisKit.

I'm wondering if there is anyway around this without having to migrate my code to the current version of QisKit.

Thanks

Comment: can you generate an openqasm file ? That should be able to still run.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Are you trying to copy your code to IBM Quantum Lab to execute? If that is the case you can downgrade the qiskit version by running `!pip install qiskit==[old version]` in a Jupyter notebook cell,  where `[old version]` is the version of Qiskit your code was based on, for example `0.20.0`. You may need to restart kernel for the old version to be reflected.

Alternatively, you should be able to run your code locally by installing old version in the same way as above or create a brand new virtual environment and install an old version.

Comment: Thankyou, this is perfect.